# Laravel allFiles() error glob Pattern exceeds the maximum allowed length of 260 characters

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have this function

```
$files=File::allFiles(base_path('folder/'));
```

in this folder there are subfolder and when I try to get files it return

```
error glob Pattern exceeds the maximum allowed length of 260 characters
```

I know it is becaus subfolder character is 280 char but how I can fix it?
I research but I don't found any solution.

Comment: This is a limitation of the length of file names. FYIY most file names cannot be more than 255 characters. In your case, you'll need to loop.

Comment: Ok, I need work with loop ok, thakyou!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a quote after `/`:

```
$files=File::allFiles(base_path('folder/));
```

Should be:

```
$files=File::allFiles(base_path('folder/'));
```